# Highlighting with :match does not appear in all buffers

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gvim

I wanted to highlight all occurence of TODO and NOTE in my code.
Looking on the internet, I inserted the following code in my .vimrc

```
:match GruvboxGreenBold /NOTE/
:2match ErrorMsg /TODO/
```

This seemed to work fine at first. When I open a file with gvim, the syntax highlights correctly.

However, as soon as I split my screen and the file appears twice, the second one get the correct highlighting but the first one loses it.
It repeats whenever I open a new buffer.

Here's a screenshot [image]

Does anyone know how to correct this behavior ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `:help :match`:

```
    Note that highlighting the last used search pattern with
    'hlsearch' is used in all windows, while the pattern defined
    with ":match" only exists in the current window.  It is kept
    when switching to another buffer.
```

It seems that the highlighting created by `:match` is local to the current window, not to the current buffer. When you split your screen, you create a new window, so you probably have to reapply your highlighting.

If you want `:match` and `:2match` to be automatically executed whenever you launch Vim or enter a new window, you could install the following autocmd:

```
augroup custom_highlighting
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter * match GruvboxGreenBold /NOTE/ | 2match ErrorMsg /TODO/
augroup END
```

Comment: Yay ! Works fine with your last workaround ! Thanks a lot !